# Sprites are disappear after some time

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Here some code for Add sprite for Enemies.....

```
_robbers = [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kNumAstroids];
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumAstroids; ++i) {
        CCSprite *asteroid = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"robber.png"];
        asteroid.visible = NO;
        [_batchNode addChild:asteroid];
        [_robbers addObject:asteroid];
   }
```

And in Update method ........

```
    double curTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
if (curTime > _nextRunemanSpawn) {
    float randSecs = [self randomValueBetween:0.20 andValue:1.0];
    _nextRunemanSpawn = randSecs + curTime;

    float randY = [self randomValueBetween:80 andValue:80];
    float randDuration = [self randomValueBetween:4.5 andValue:4.5];
    float randDuration1 = [self randomValueBetween:1.0 andValue:1.0];

    CCSprite *asteroid = [_robbers objectAtIndex:_nextRobber];
    _nextRobber++;

    if (_nextRobber >= _robbers.count) {
        _nextRobber = 1;
    }
    [asteroid stopAllActions];
    asteroid.position = ccp(winSize.width +asteroid.contentSize.width / 2 , randY);
    asteroid.visible = YES;

    [asteroid runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:randDuration position:ccp(-winSize.width-asteroid.contentSize.width, 0)],
                         [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)],nil]];
```

All Sprites are Move from right to left in screen
when Sprite crosses the middle of the screen it automatically disappear
what is the reason for this problem ??

Comment: Any chance that by the time the sprite reaches the center of the screen the line : [_robbers objectAtIndex:_nextRobber] gives you the same asteroid object for which you reset the position ? By looking at your code basically it looks fine. Also how you calculate winSize ? Do you manipulate asteroid objects somewhere else in your code ?

Comment: I have define  #define kNumAstroids 2  if i will define it as 15 no asteroid will disappear ......why ?

Comment: I think this is because _nextRunemanSpawn is too small so that until the asteroid reached the center of the screen enough time will be passed so that you get the same asteroid from the _robbers array and then you stop the action and reset the position (in your update method after the if test)

Comment: my hunch is also that the move anim runs again before the previous has ended. Try stopping all actions before running the sequence, you may see sprites moving back in again from the right.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previously mentioned statement from LearnCocos2D. It is also possible that you are adding multiple objects and reaching the end of the capacity in the line

```
_robbers = [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kNumAstroids];
```

If you try to spawn more objects than whatever number you have specified for kNumAsteroids it will remove the oldest object and use the new one in its place. I.e. if kNumAsteroids is 5, you have 5 on the screen and then add a sixth, 1 will become 6 and its position will be whatever you set it to.